# How to process an image with OpenCV onPictureTaken?

Tags: android, opencv, opencv3.1

I've been trying to process an image as soon as the picture was taken i.e. in the `onPictureTaken()` callback. As it was to my understanding I should convert the byte array to an OpenCV matrix, but the entire app freezes when I try to do that. Basically all I did was this:

```
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] bytes, Camera camera) {
    Log.w(TAG, "picture taken!");

    if (bytes != null) {
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        Mat matImage = new Mat();

        // This is where my app freezes.
        Utils.bitmapToMat(image, matImage);

        Log.w(TAG, matImage.dump());
    }

    mCamera.startPreview();
    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);
}
```

Does anyone know why it freezes and how to solve it?

*Note:* I've used the OpenCV4Android tutorial 3 as a base.

**Update 1:** I've also tried to parste the bytes (without any success) as follows:

```
Mat mat = Imgcodecs.imdecode(
    new MatOfByte(bytes), 
    Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED
);
```

**Update 2:** Supposedly this should work, it did not for me though.

```
Mat mat = new Mat(1, bytes.length, CvType.CV_8UC3);
mat.put(0, 0, bytes);
```

Nor did this variant:

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
Mat mat = new Mat(image.getHeight(), image.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
mat.put(0, 0, bytes);
```

**Update 3:** This did not work for me either:

```
Mat mat = new MatOfByte(bytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got some help of a colleague of mine. He managed to fix the problem by doing the following:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options(); // This was missing.
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length, opts);

Mat mat = new Mat();
Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, mat);

// Note: when the matrix is to large mat.dump() might also freeze your app.
Log.w(TAG, mat.size());
```

Hopefully this'll help all of you who are also struggling with this.